# Cursor pagination with limit confilict

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, pagination

I try to create a cursor paginate base on the date.

Let assume the first 11 records that have exact date value.
I set the limit per page to the 10.

After digging in some cursor pagination library I figure out the next cursor has greater identifier ( in my case identifier is DateTime ).
So if write the query like below for second page the first element is 12th record, not 11th.

`where date > '10th record date'`

And because of the limit, the 11th record will not show on the first page either.

There is no 11th element on the first or second page.

How I solve this? I can't mix it with `id` because the result is sorted by `date` and there is no guaranty for `id` to be in order.

So how to create cursor pagination with having limit per page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional identifier so the sorting keys uniquely define each row.  Let me assume that `id` is the primary key.  Then you would use:

```
where date > @date or (date = @date and id > @id)
```

`@date` and `@id` would be the maximum value on the previous page.

In some databases, you can phrase this as:

```
where (date, id) > (@date, @id)
```

And in many databases, you can just use `offset/fetch` for pagination and not worry about the exact logic.

Comment: As I say in my question there is no guaranty the id value is sorted. the date is not a `created_date` and because of that the new record can have the oldest date, `id > @id` or `id < @id` is not working

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi . . . That is not the expression in this answer.  The filtering condition includes both the date and the id.

Comment: id can be anything. there is no guaranty that be greater or smaller, I can't filter by id, Also I can't use offset for cursor pagination.

Comment: Ok I solve the problem by addint `id` in order by ( order by date,id ). I only have one question what is the name of this type expression ? `(date, id) > (@date, @id)` I search for mysql and found nothing

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi . . . That expression is a "tuple comparison".  Not all databases support it, but MySQL does:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71764afbeff3086e72c93a6ee2b1db6c.